# Calculating field to input into MySQL table based on form input and variable from second MySQL table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am stuck on a query/calculation based on two different tables (joined by a third table). A form collects information to input into tbl2, tbl1 is linked to tbl2 via foreign key. I need to calculate and insert a value into tbl2 based on form data and a value from tbl1.

My Query + Calculation looks like this:

```
$res = $user->runQuery("SELECT binWeight FROM jobBins jb JOIN butchJobOpen bjo ON bjo.jobBins_binID = jb.binID JOIN butchJobClose bjc ON bjc.butchJobOpen_butchJobNum = bjo.butchJobNum WHERE bjo.butchJobNum = '$butchJobOpen_butchJobNum'");
$res->execute(); 
$row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//Calculate $trimYield     
$trimYield = $row['binWeight'] / $trimWeight;
```

The query should use a form value $butchJobOpen_butchJobNum, verify the bin exists on the join conditions, and return the weight of the bin....this works fine as a standalone query, however, I cannot get any results from my calculation...I am sure I am just missing something stupid...but I am stuck, so I lob this up to the merciless SO community, in hopes that while getting downvoted, someone will point me in the right direction while ridiculing my obvious mistake.

Comment: That is assigned from the form itself.

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is what you have to do

1. Get rid of all the home-brewed stuff. Instead of whatever `$user->runQuery` use vanilla PDO.
2. Verify the input. See whether your variable contain anything useful.
3. Use PDO properly, utilizing prepared statements.
4. Make your code to give at least *any* outcome.
5. **Do realize that above instruction is not a ready to use solution on a golden plate** but just steps you have to make **yourself** to investigate the problem.

So

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

var_dump("that argle-bargle var name I can't type it:",$butchJobOpen_butchJobNum);

$sql = "SELECT binWeight FROM jobBins jb 
        JOIN butchJobOpen bjo ON bjo.jobBins_binID = jb.binID 
        JOIN butchJobClose bjc ON bjc.butchJobOpen_butchJobNum =  bjo.butchJobNum 
        WHERE bjo.butchJobNum = ?";
$res = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$res->execute([$butchJobOpen_butchJobNum]);
$binWeight = $res->fetchColumn();
var_dump("bin weight:", $binWeight);
var_dump("trim weight:", $trimWeight);

$trimYield = $binWeight / $trimWeight;
var_dump("finally", $trimYield);
```

The var_dump part is most essential, giving you a clue what's going on in your program. A 10000 times more fruitful than a hour of staring at the code or a whine on SO.

The point here is to verify every bloody variable's state. And yo see whether it contains anything expected.

Comment: I apologize for whining, kind of...whining to myself whilst staring down code I can't quite figure out doesn't do me any good.  Whining about the inevitable down voting/mockery that will occur as a result of asking a relatively simple question on SO to those who can barely be bothered with such questions tends to be more fruitful than not.  Might get a downvote, but also might get help.  Although your answer about canning my home brewed functions is not helpful, your code reminded me of why I might have been getting empty results....I appreciate your well thought out response.